# Поменять значения измерений массива между собой

Tags: c#

```
int[,] numbers = new int[2, 4] { {1,4,8,8}, {6,6,6,6} };
```

Поменять значения измерений массива между собой.
Нужно чтобы значение 1,4,8,8 было заменено на 6,6,6,6, а 6,6,6,6 на 1,4,4,8

Comment: как вы сами пробовали это решить? приведите примеры вашего кода

Comment: Если возьмете не двумерный массив, а массив массивов, то ваша задача решится примерно так: `(numbers[0], numbers[1]) = (numbers[1], numbers[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[,] numbers = new int[2, 4] { {1,4,8,8}, {6,6,6,6} };    
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int temp = numbers[0, i];
    numbers[0, i] = numbers[1, i];
    numbers[1, i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @aa_talanin (не хочу код в комментах писать), напоминаю, что в C#7 есть возможность обмена двух переменных не используя временную:

```
int[,] numbers = new int[2, 4] { { 1, 4, 8, 8 }, { 6, 6, 6, 6 } };
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    (numbers[0, i], numbers[1, i]) = (numbers[1, i], numbers[0, i]);
}
```

Не то, чтобы я этим пользовался в продакшене - так, напомнить о новых возможностях языка:

- [What's new in C# 7.0 #tuples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples)